# Libreoffice 3.5 won't launch from Desktop Shortcut: Ubuntu 11.10 Unity

Tags: libreoffice, shortcuts

I've upgraded my Libreoffice to the recent 3.5 version. Before, I was using LO 3.45 and it had no problems on launching from the Desktop Shortcut. Anyways, when I upgraded and tried to create a shortcut from the launcher it reported this,

"The application launcher "libreoffice3.5-base.desktop" has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe."

Any ideas of fixing this. Thanks in advance:

Regards

Comment: Why are you still using Ubuntu 11.10? If you upgrade to 14.04, you won't have to update again until 2019.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter directory: `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`.
2. Find and right-click on *LibreOffice* file, choose *Copy to the desktop*. An "empty" icon named *LibreOffice* should appear on your desktop.
3. Open the terminal and type: `locate startcenter.png`.
4. There will be directories to LibreOffice icons. Enter one of them, choose an icon of proper size and double click it - just open and close it (I've chosen 48x48 icon from the directory: `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps`).
5. Then right-click on "empty" icon named *LibreOffice* on your desktop and
   choose *Properties*.
6. Double-click on the icon on the upper left corner of the *Properties*
   window. In the new *Last in use* window choose the libreoffice-main.png file and
   confirm your choice.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Is more aesier than that, just install "alacarte" with `sudo apt-get install alacarte`, then in the dash, search for it.

Once is open, navegate to the office section, select the libreoffice app that you want to create a link and clic on properties.

Do not change the content, just close the propierties window once opened. (It sounds weird, but that the way)

Do the same for all the libreoffice apps that you want to create a link, once you did it, close alacarte; drag and drop the icon of the libreooffice app that you make the process.