# Why I can't put LibreOffice icons on the desktop?

Tags: 12.04, icons, shortcuts

Having trouble putting LibreOffice icons on the desktop. When I click and drag from the applications, the LibreOffice icon does not appear correctly, and does not work. Is there a  fix for this?

Comment: Did you followed the method mentioned in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/67934/62483)? Also, are you sure that you can open it from the origin icon?

Comment: I think there have an solution
http://askubuntu.com/questions/107198/libreoffice-3-5-wont-launch-from-desktop-shortcut-ubuntu-11-10-unity

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Perhaps it's a unity bug. I created my own launcher manually.

First I followed the instructions here to create shortcut:
[Desktop shortcut to create a new desktop shortcut doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142159/desktop-shortcut-to-create-a-new-desktop-shortcut-doesnt-do-anything)

Looked for the command in `/usr/share/menu/libreoffice-calc`
which is:

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice --calc
```

Used icon found here:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/libreoffice-calc.png
```